# How and where to close() my database to stop get E/SQLiteLog: (283)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

When i open database file in DB browser its empty. And i get this E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 16 frames from WAL file.Is it proper to use Room for saving the data and populate it back when app is closed and vice versa.Ill be glad if someone can help ,thanks.

/this is my instantiation in db class /

```
public static synchronized NoteDataBase getInstance(Context context){

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                NoteDataBase.class , "note_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
    }
    return instance;
}
} 
@Override
public void close() {
    super.close();
    instance = null;
}

public void backup(Context context) {
    instance.close();
    //......... backup the file
    getInstance(context);
}
```

/and my Repository/

```
 public NoteRepository(Application application) {
    dataBase = NoteDataBase.getInstance(application);
    noteDao = dataBase.noteDao();
    allNotes = noteDao.getAllNotes();
```

}

/some of my viewmodel/

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel  {

public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application)  {
    super(application);
    repository = new NoteRepository(application);
    allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
}

public void insert(Note note) {
    repository.insert(note);
}
```

}

/And my Fragment where i save some results/

```
private void saveNote(){

    String savedscore = finalScore.getText().toString();
    ArrayList<String> daycheks =  new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
        daycheks.add(itemList.get(i).toString());
    }

    Note note = new Note(savedscore , daycheks);
    model.insert(note);

    Toast.makeText(getContext() , "Result saved" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When backing up the database you should either fully checkpoint the database (closing the database is one option (the simplest)) before backing up or backup the **-wal** and the **-shm** files along with the actual database file.

- the **-wal**/**-shm** or **-journal** files are the same name as the database file suffixed with the respective extension.

Another option is to open the database in journal mode using [setJournalMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#setJournalMode(androidx.room.RoomDatabase.JournalMode)).

- The difference between **WAL** and Journal mode is

  - that in WAL mode changes are applied to the **-wal** file not the database itself (although the **-wal** file is accessed as if it is part of the database), roll-back is then a matter of deleting the respective data from the **-wal** file.
  - Whilst with journal mode the database is changed and those changes are written to the **-journal** file, roll-back undoes the changes according to the journal file.
  - See [Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) for more comprehensive information.

As can be seen if you copy a database without the database being check-pointed and without the **-wal** file then data may be missing.

## Example

The following example mimics backing up the database, including closing the database (but skips the actual backup) after adding some rows. Note that for convenience this is done on the main thread.

The DB Class :-

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities = MyTable.class,version = 1)
public abstract class NoteDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static String DBNAME = "mydb";
    static NoteDataBase instance;

    abstract MyTableDao getMyTableDao();
    public static synchronized NoteDataBase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, NoteDataBase.class,DBNAME)
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.close();
        instance = null;
    }

    public void backup(Context context) {
        instance.close();
        //......... backup the file
        getInstance(context);
    }
}
```

- i.e. basically your class but importantly with a backup method, that closes the database and then sets the instance variable to null, effectively forcing an open when it is next used.

An Activity that uses the above :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NoteDataBase mDB;
    MyTableDao mMyTableDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("APPINFO","Retrieving the Database Instance");
        mDB = NoteDataBase.getInstance(this);
        Log.d("APPINFO","Retrieving the Database DAO");
        mMyTableDao = mDB.getMyTableDao();
        Log.d("APPINFO","Inserting Data (10 rows)");
        for (int i=1;i < 11; i++) {
            mMyTableDao.insertMyTableRow(new MyTable("MYVALUE" + i));
        }
        Log.d("APPINFO","Mock backup/close");
        mDB.backup(this);
        Log.d("APPINFO","Retrieveing the Database Instance after the close");
        mDB = NoteDataBase.getInstance(this);
        Log.d("APPINFO","Retrieving Rows from the Database");
        for(MyTable m: mDB.getMyTableDao().getAllMyTableRows()) {
            Log.d("MYTABLEINFO","ID = " + m.getId() + " VALUE = " + m.getValue());
        }
        Log.d("APPINFO","Closing the database");
        mDB.close();
        MyTable m = mDB.getMyTableDao().getMyTableRowById(1L);
        Log.d("MYTABLEINFO","ID = " + m.getId() + " VALUE = " + m.getValue());
    }
}
```

### Result (Log) :-

```
2019-10-21 15:47:58.689 16269-16269/? D/APPINFO: Retrieving the Database Instance
2019-10-21 15:47:58.699 16269-16269/? D/APPINFO: Retrieving the Database DAO
2019-10-21 15:47:58.701 16269-16269/? D/APPINFO: Inserting Data (10 rows)
2019-10-21 15:47:58.743 16269-16269/? D/APPINFO: Mock backup/close
2019-10-21 15:47:58.752 16269-16269/? D/APPINFO: Retrieveing the Database Instance after the close
2019-10-21 15:47:58.752 16269-16269/? D/APPINFO: Retrieving Rows from the Database
2019-10-21 15:47:58.773 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 1 VALUE = MYVALUE1
2019-10-21 15:47:58.773 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 2 VALUE = MYVALUE2
2019-10-21 15:47:58.773 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 3 VALUE = MYVALUE3
2019-10-21 15:47:58.773 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 4 VALUE = MYVALUE4
2019-10-21 15:47:58.773 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 5 VALUE = MYVALUE5
2019-10-21 15:47:58.773 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 6 VALUE = MYVALUE6
2019-10-21 15:47:58.773 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 7 VALUE = MYVALUE7
2019-10-21 15:47:58.773 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 8 VALUE = MYVALUE8
2019-10-21 15:47:58.774 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 9 VALUE = MYVALUE9
2019-10-21 15:47:58.774 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 10 VALUE = MYVALUE10
2019-10-21 15:47:58.774 16269-16269/? D/APPINFO: Closing the database
2019-10-21 15:47:58.784 16269-16269/? E/ROOM: Invalidation tracker is initialized twice :/.
2019-10-21 15:47:58.784 16269-16269/? D/MYTABLEINFO: ID = 1 VALUE = MYVALUE1
```

- Note the last but 1 line, this is because the old instance was used instead of getting a new instance *(really `mDB = NoteDataBase.getInstance(this);` should have been used)*.

Of note is that the database, after running the above has an empty **-wal** file :-

[image]

- Therefore the database has been fully check-pointed.

Copying this file from device explorer and opening in an SQLite tool (Navicat) shows :-

[image]

- i.e. the data inserted exists, as does the room_master_table and the android_metadata table

## Alternative to Close

An alternative to closing the database would be to use the [PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(?)](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint)

If the DB class included the following methods :-

```
public void checkpoint() {
    int attempts = 0;
    int max_attempts = 10;
    Cursor csr;
    SupportSQLiteDatabase ssd  = instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
    if (isWALOn(ssd)) {
        Log.d("CHKPOINTINFO","Attempt " +  (attempts + 1));
        while (checkpoint(ssd) > 0 && attempts++ < max_attempts) { }
    }
}

private boolean isWALOn(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
    boolean rv = false;
    Cursor csr = db.query("PRAGMA journal_mode");
    if  (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        if (csr.getString(0).toLowerCase().equals("wal")) rv = true;
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}

private int checkpoint(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d("CHKPOINTINFO","Attempting Database Ceckpoint");
    int blocked = 0;
    int pages_to_checkpoint = 0;
    int checkpointed_pages = 0;
    Cursor csr = db.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)");
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        blocked = csr.getInt(0);
        pages_to_checkpoint = csr.getInt(1);
        checkpointed_pages = csr.getInt(2);
    }
    csr.close();
    Log.d("CHKPOINTINFO",
            "Checkpoint values Blocked = " + blocked +
                    " Pages to Checkpoint = " + pages_to_checkpoint +
                    " Pages Checkpointed = " + checkpointed_pages
    );
    if (blocked > 0) return -1;
    if (checkpointed_pages < pages_to_checkpoint) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

- note Logging added for testing, typically this would be removed.

The instead of using `mDB.backup()`, `mDB.checkpoint()` could be used. The advantage of this is that the database remains open.

Comment: I do the following , but i get no result.Maybe i have some misunderstood.I make some edit on question.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to close the database in onCleared method of my main ViewModel, then the error log disappeared.

```
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(private val reviewRepository: ReviewRepository,
                                            private val favoriteRepository: FavoriteRepository,
                                            private val firebaseService: FirebaseService,
                                            private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
                                            private val toiletDb: ToiletDb)
: ViewModel() {

// Close database when the ViewModel is cleared
override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    toiletDb.close()
}
```